# C# Inherited Class With Inherited Child Class Collection

Tags: c#

What is the best design pattern for the following scenarios

These are my base classes:

```
class Vehicle
{
  List<Tire> Tires 
}

class Tire
{
}
```

These are my derived classes:

```
class Truck: Vehicle
{
  List<TruckTire> Tires 
}

class TruckTire: Tire
{
}
```

Problem 1

I want Truck - Tires point to the same list as Vehicle - Tires but in order to that in Truck - Tires has to pull Vehicle - Tires and cast it. At the moment this is what I'm doing

```
class Truck
{
  List<TruckTires> TruckTires
  {
    get 
    {
      return Base.Tires.Cast<TruckTires>().ToList();
    }
    set
    {
      base.Tires = value.Cast<Tires>().ToList()
    }
  }
}
```

This opens up additional problem and that this doesn't work.

```
  TruckTires.Add(new TruckTire());
```

As it will call the getter but it never calls the setter. To get around that I do this

```
List<TruckTires> _tempTruckTires = TruckTires;
_temoTruckTires.add(new TruckTire());
TruckTires = _tempTruckTires
```

Problem 2

I want to instantiate Truck by passing Vehicle to the constructor,however this does not work and mapping all the properties to the base class is not an ideal solution

```
class Truck
{
  public Truck(Vehicle vehicle)
  {
     base = vehicle 
  }
}
```

Problem 3

How do I cast Vehicle with a Tires list to a Truck with a TruckTire list, at the moment this is what I am doing.

```
Truck truck = new Truck(vehicle);
foreach(Tire tire in Vehicle.Tires)
{
  TruckTire truckTire = new TrickTire(tire);
  Truck.TruckTires.Add(truckTire);
}
```

I am even having a hard time finding articles that cover this.

Comment: You might be suffering from over-inheritance. Is there a reason TruckTire needs to be a subtype of Tire? Related reading: [Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: @TyCobb OP already has TruckTire deriving from Tire. It's in the second code snippet.

Comment: TruckTire has a number of properties and methods that are on top of tire. I can add these methods and properties to the Tire class which will really simplify my design but now I have properties in my Tire class that are only relevant if Tire is used by a Truck object. (I am not sure that is a better trade off) (My objects are huge already)

Comment: @itsme86 Thanks, I missed that. JohnSoer, why do you really need a difference between a truck and car tire? A tire is a tire. This isn't like Cat and Dog. They both have grip, diameter, width, etc. Can't you just have a Tire and set the data that make it a truck tire?

Answer (score 0):

For problem 2, you probably want to call a base class constructor on `Vehicle` that does the copy over. You'll need to make sure that `Vehicle` has an appropriate constructor that takes a `Vehicle` and copies the appropriate properties over.

```
class Truck
{
  public Truck(Vehicle vehicle)
  base(vehicle)
  {
  }
}
```

For problems 1 and 3, you may be able to avoid some of your cast problems with a change to your initial base classes. If you use an interface for your Tires, you'd be able to insert `Tire`s into the `Vehicle` class and `TruckTire`s in your `Truck` class. However, that does mean that Truck would have to cast any `ITire`s that come out of the list back to `TruckTire` when you use it to get access to anything specific to `TruckTire`.

```
interface ITire {}

class Vehicle
{
  List<ITire> Tires 
}

class Tire : ITire
{
}
```

I'm not positive this will solve everything for you, but might be worth trying.

Last thing I wanted to mention, the reason you're having problems with your getter in `TruckTires` is because of the `ToList()` at the end

```
get 
{
  return Base.Tires.Cast<TruckTires>().ToList();
}
```

`ToList()` takes the enumeration returned from `Cast<>()` and creates a *new* list, unrelated to `base.Tires`. You need to ultimately return `base.Tires` to not have to re-set the Property, but your typing and cast issues seem to be what's blocking you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create Tires in Vehicle

```
List<Vehicle> Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
v.Tires.Add(new Tire(16));
Vehicles.Add(v);
VehiTruck tr = new VehiTruck();
tr.TireTrucks.Add(new TireTruck(20, 20));
tr.TireTrucks.Add(new TireTruck(21, 21));
Debug.WriteLine(tr.TireTrucks.Count());
Vehicles.Add(tr);
foreach (Vehicle vv in Vehicles)
{
    if (vv is VehiTruck)
    {
        VehiTruck vt = (VehiTruck)vv;
        Debug.WriteLine(vt.TireTrucks.Count);
        Debug.WriteLine(vt.TireTrucks[0].Size);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(vv.Tires.Count);
        Debug.WriteLine(vv.Tires[0].Size);
    }
}

public class Tire
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public Tire(int size)
    {
        Size = size;
    }
}
public class TireTruck : Tire
{
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public TireTruck(int size, int rating) : base(size)
    {
        Rating = rating;
    }
}
public class Vehicle
{
    public List<Tire> Tires { get; } = new List<Tire>();
    public Vehicle() { }
    public Vehicle(Vehicle v) { }

}
public class VehiTruck : Vehicle
{
    public List<TireTruck> TireTrucks { get; } = new List<TireTruck>();
    public VehiTruck() { }
    public VehiTruck(Vehicle v) : base(v)
    { }
}
```